# prevent dbl click not working on pop up z-layer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a layer that pops up when the user clicks a link, 
inside this z-layer there are another links  that load videos,
something weird happens only when they double click on the links.
If they just click once it works fine. I know this is not the best solution to fix the problem
but I need it to work while i'm figuring out what the real problem is.

I tried putting the link in the home page and it works fine.
Any help is welcome.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.answer_link').bind('dblclick',function(e){
    alert();
 // e.preventDefault();
    })
});
```

**HTML**

```
<?php echo '<div class="answer_recorded_container">
    <a class="answer_link" href="javascript: getvideo(\''.$d->video.'\',\''.$owner.'\');">
    <div>' .$d->question.'
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>  
    </a>
</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to stop "dbclick" event completely you can just return false when event is triggers.

```
$('.answer_link').bind('dblclick',function(e){
//e.preventDefault();
return false;
console.log('asjdhfkjasfhjasd');
   });
```

Suggestion: rather than binding events to elements try delegate or on methods.